# How can I use Matlab to calculate the probability of getting at least $q$ zeros in a binary sequence?

Tags: matlab, math

For a project (not educationally) from a friend of mine I need to do some calculation. I have very little experience in matlab (and 7 years ago I had some lectures in java so I know what a for loop, etc is).

**Question**

Given a binary sequence *S* of length *m* , with *n*<*m* ones and *(m-n)* zeros (we don't know which elements have value 0 or 1).

Suppose we modify the sequence such that we randomly change *x*<*m* fixed elements of the sequence  into a one or into a zero (with *p* = 0.5 1/2 for both events happening), what is the probability that the number of zeros is at least *q* < *m* ?

(By 'fixed elements' I mean that we know which elements of the sequence could be changed (flipping to the other value or remains the same))

So I'm looking for a method to calculate *P(m,n,x,q)* for example in settings with values like

*m = 1000*;

*0 < n < 0.3m*

*0 < x < 0.6m*;

*0.5 m < q < m*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear (at least for me), whether n, x and q are random numbers, or fixed values. I've written something as if they were random numbers. It's easily changeable if it's not the case.

Every line of the code is explained in comments (%) in the code.

```
%This is the number of bits

m=1000;

%This is a counter needed for the probability calculation

count=0;

%Loop needed for the probability calculation

for i = 1:1000000

%This is a random number generator that generates m (1000 in this case)
%random numbers between 0 and 1

randomseq=rand(1,m);

%This creates a random number between 0 and 1 and then multiplies it by
%0.29 so it can actually be between 0 and 0.29. If n is not a random
%number, then change it with the fixed value that it has.

n=rand(1,1)*0.29; 

%This line is for the following:
%If a number is less than n, then make it 1, else make it 0 (this is
%needed so you can acquire a probability for the number of ones and the
%number of zeros). Here you will have around  n*1000 ones, but not
%equal since randomseq is a random vector with 1000 elements and those
%are too few numbers so it can create a real distribution.

onezerorand=randomseq<n;

%That's why this is needed, just in case if the number of ones go over
%30%. If it goes over 30%, than make the numones coef 0.29

if sum(onezerorand)>=300
   numones=0.29;
else

%This is a coef which represent the number of ones, but in probability
%terms (between 0 and 1). Mean just calculates the mean value between
%the zeros and the ones, which is essentially the probability.

    numones=mean(onezerorand);
end

%The rest of the numbers are zero, so you get the probability by
%subtracting numones from 1

numzeros=1-numones;

%This creates a random number x between 0 and 0.59. If x is not a
%random number, the same comment goes as for n.

x=rand(1,1)*0.59;

%There is a 50% chance that x of the ones will be changed to zeros and
%vice versa, so you create a random number between 0 and 0.5 and
%multiply it by x.

p0=rand(1,1)*0.5;
p1=1-p0;
x_ones=rand(1,1)*p0*x;
x_zeros=rand(1,1)*p1*x;

%You add the changed zeros to the ones and the changed ones to the
%zeros and you subtract the changed ones from the ones and the changed
%zeros from the zeros, so you can get the last value of the number of
%zeros.

new_numones=numones-numones*x_ones+numzeros*x_zeros;
new_numzeros=numzeros-numzeros*x_zeros+numones*x_ones;

%You create a random number between 0.51 and 0.99, so you can compare
%the number of zeros to it. If q is not a random number, the same
%comment as the one for x and n.

q=rand(1,1)*0.48+0.51;

%You compare the number of zeros to the new random number. If it's
%bigger than it, than you raise the counter, if not, you do nothing.
%You repeat this 1000000 times so you can get a good probability
%estimation and the number you get is the probability of this occuring.

if new_numzeros>q
    count=count+1;
end
end

%The probability of this event occuring

prob=count/1000000;
```

By my estimations, the probability is around 60%, with random coefs n, x and q. If they are fixed values, I would not know, since I don't know their exact values.

Comment: Thanks I will look at it tomorrow.  The variables are known,  not random.

Comment: Then just change:
n=rand(1,1)*0.29;  with n=0.25 for example,
x=rand(1,1)*0.59; with x=0.55 for example,
and q=rand(1,1)*0.48+0.51; with q=0.6 for example, where you will just add the real values instead of my examples.

I've tried it with now with this values and the probability is around 55%

Comment: Write again tomorrow if you need anything, or just post if this works out as it should. Cheers :)